# Replace Turkish letters with English letters

Tags: php, html, regex

I want to replace every Turkish letter in a sentence with an english letter , I try the following function :

```
$title_result = "Türkiye'nin en iyi oranlari ile Lider Bahis Sitesi";
$turkish = array("ı", "ğ", "ü", "ş", "ö", "ç");//turkish letters
$english   = array("i", "g", "u", "s", "o", "c");//english cooridinators letters

$final_title = str_replace($turkish, $english, $title_result);//replace php function
print_r($turkish);//when printing this i got: Array ( [0] => Ä± [1] => ÄŸ [2] => Ã¼ [3] => ÅŸ [4] => Ã¶ [5] => Ã§ ) 
return $final_title;
```

i think the problem in the Turkish characters but i do not know how i can make the php read this characters correctly to make the replacement properly . I need you suggestions please??

Comment: Your code works well on my machine. Maybe there's something wrong with your config - check for mbstring: http://php.net/manual/en/book.mbstring.php

Comment: the final title is not showing or printed because the str_replace does not work so it has no value

Comment: see the php info for mbstring, please (`php -i | grep mbstring` in linux terminal). it shoulb be enabled, cause I guess turkish characters can be stored in two bytes instead of one

Comment: Why such replacements? If you expect that the Turkish letters cannot be used, you might be wrong. And if they really cannot be used, it is usually better to avoid losing information too much and replace e.g. “ş” by “sh” rather than “s”.

Comment: worked fine on [phpfiddle](http://phpfiddle.org)

Comment: @k102 I check the php_info() and the mbstring is enabled

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela K. Korpela I have to replace them because the return words will be the title of the page that i will create (url) and i can not have turkish letters in the url bad for SEO

Answer (score 4):

Have you noticed that you're printing `$turkish` and not the replaced string (i.e. `$final_title`)? You see an array because you're printing the array. If you're printing the array alone on your browser, you see those messed-up characters probably because the output isn't UTF-8 encoded. However if you do this (notice the meta tag):

```
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<?php
$title_result = "Türkiye'nin en iyi oranlari ile Lider Bahis Sitesi";
$turkish = array("ı", "ğ", "ü", "ş", "ö", "ç");//turkish letters
$english   = array("i", "g", "u", "s", "o", "c");//english cooridinators letters

$final_title = str_replace($turkish, $english, $title_result);//replace php function
print_r($turkish);
```

You will see the characters correctly. But that's not the matter. The str_replace() works fine. It should work fine.

Comment: I use latin-1 as acharset in my header file because utf8 can not print out the turkish characters in my browser. My problem is that the str_replace do not do the replacement , the old string and the new string are the same

Comment: But in `$title_result` there are no turkish characters! So `str_replace` has nothing to do with this string.

Comment: What's the character encoding of the file where this code is? Try changing it to UTF-8 without BOM, or UTF-8. Does it work? (be careful though, because this can mess up your file, make a backup before anything. I do Ctrl+A, Ctrl+X, change encoding, Ctrl+V on Notepad++). Encoding is a trick I haven't mastered.

Comment: @k102 The second character is a ü... that's the only character. lol.

Comment: @k102 yeah, the replacement works for me, but Basel says it doesn't work for him. I'd say he'll have to play around with encoding till it works.

Comment: guys thank for all your comments , i tried the code also on phpfiddle it works find but on my website it does not ,even i changed all the page encoding to utf8 without BOM but nothing happend , i am running of options :(

Comment: @BaselShbeb I'm sorry, you need to keep playing with encoding. That's all I can say D:

Comment: My requirement was to allow user to search using English keyboard, so behind the seen I converted text to lowercase prior to replace. This way, mb_strtolower('Şöhü', "UTF-8").
This will convert all  UTF-8 chars to lowercase. Note: strtolower() won't help here.

Answer (score 4):

What about grand letter,
My solution is:

```
function url_make($str){
    $before = array('ı', 'ğ', 'ü', 'ş', 'ö', 'ç', 'İ', 'Ğ', 'Ü', 'Ö', 'Ç'); // , '\'', '""'
    $after   = array('i', 'g', 'u', 's', 'o', 'c', 'i', 'g', 'u', 'o', 'c'); // , '', ''

    $clean = str_replace($before, $after, $str);
    $clean = preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9 ]/', '', $clean);
    $clean = preg_replace('!\s+!', '-', $clean);
    $clean = strtolower(trim($clean, '-'));

return $clean;
}

echo url_make('Bu Çocuğu Kim İşe Aldı'); // bu-cocugu-kim-ise-aldi
echo url_make('Birisi"nin adı'); // birisinin-adi
echo url_make("I'll make all happen"); // ill-make-all-happen
```

To produce i-ll-make-all-happen instead of ill-make-all-happen, just add '\'' and '"' to the list of $before, and add ' ' and ' ' to the list of after