# Php How can I convert Ö letter with iconv

Tags: php, character-encoding, translation, iconv

I try to convert Turkish letter to English letter like ı->i ğ->g.I can translate almost most letter but except for ö,ü.
Is there a method or article you can recommend?

my code:

```
$text="ödeme yöntem Şeçinizİ ü,ö";
var_dump(iconv("utf-8","ascii//TRANSLIT",$text));
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Replace Turkish letters with English letters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19582497/replace-turkish-letters-with-english-letters)

Comment: No,I have work with iconv or other method,replace can't accept.